# Why are we here, specifically, saying that ArrayList is not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

Description: If we use same object reference among multiple threads, no object is thread safe. Similarly, if any collection reference is shared among multiple threads then that collection is not thread-safe since other threads can access it. So, Why are we here specifically saying that ArrayList is not thread-safe? What about the other Collections?

Comment: If we use same object reference among multiple threads, no object is thread safe. No, Your hypothesis are wrong

Comment: If two threads are being executed simultaneously to change a value in object reference, won't that create an interference ? Doesn't that mean that they are not threat-safe?

Comment: not really no, if its protected with locks for example then it is thread-safe

Comment: Shared mutable state is never thread safe.  It has to be guarded appropriately to manage thread access or be made immutable.  That's why immutable objects and functional style is desirable - immutable objects are always thread-safe.   They come at the cost of greater memory consumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is unsynchronized in implementation. When an object is unsynchronized it means that is is not locked while being modified structurally. `A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.`
What you are referring to is an array which the elements are being added to or being deleted from and can be modified this differs from it having its value being set.

Reference is in regards with the pointer of the start of the array but how many elements are there is in question and having an unsynchronized object being modified in the sense of elements while the elements are being iterated over by another thread the integrity of the elements in the list is hard to guarantee. I hope I was able to convey the message plainly.

Look for more details here in Oracle: [Array List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

ArrayList:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.) This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the list. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method.

ConcurrentModificationException:

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification.

Comment: Note that Hirad's meaning by "unsynchronized" is that is that you can run the method with multiple threads at a time(Which would cause strange problems). It doesn't have to be used in keyword "synchronized" it can be used it something like Lock.lock() and Lock.unlock(). There are some situations where there could have multiple threads running the method(For example optimistic read or tryOptimisticRead in StampedLock or other classes.

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand the meaning of "thread-safe."

When we say "class X is thread-safe," We are *not* saying that *you* don't have to worry about the thread-safety of a program that uses it. If you build a program using nothing but thread-safe objects, that does *not* guarantee that your program will be thread-safe.

So what *does* it guarantee?

Suppose you have a `List`. Suppose that two threads, A and B, each write different values to the same index in the list, suppose that some thread C reads from that index, and suppose that none of those three threads uses any synchronization.

If the list is "thread-safe," then you can be assured that thread C will get one of three possible values:

- The value that thread A wrote,
- The value that thread B wrote,
- The value that was stored at that index before either thread A or thread B wrote.

If the list is *not* thread-safe, then any of those same three things could happen, but also, other things could happen:

- Thread C could get a value that was never in the list,
- The list could behave in broken ways in the future for thread C even if no other thread continues to use it,
- The program could crash,
- etc. (I don't know how many other strange things could happen.)

When we say that a class is "thread-safe" we are saying that it will always behave in predictable, reasonable ways, even when its methods are concurrently called by multiple threads.

If you write a program that uses a "thread-safe" list, and if it depends on thread C reading one particular value of the three possibilities that I listed above, then *your program* has a thread-safety problem, even though the list itself does not.

Comment: I understood the thread-safety in the following way:
If A, B both do a structural  modification on the list, they do it one after other fashion. I mean, the list would be locked for A until it completes its operation and then for B. Is this good understanding?

Comment: @manikantanvsr, Forget about "structural modification." I intentionally chose an example above in which it is not necessary for the list structure to change. _Any_ concurrent access to an "unsafe" object has the potential to crash your program or worse\* if at least one of those accesses is a write. [\* For "worse," imagine a life-critical application that makes a wrong decision, a program that stores bad data in a mission-critical database, etc.\]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked but I think that all standard Collection implementations state if they are thread-safe or not. So you know if you can share that collection among different threads without synchronization.

CopyOnWriteArrayList for example is a thread-safe List implementation.

Comment: So, if it is a thread-safe collection, without declaring it as synchronized, we can use it among multiple threads preventing interference. Because of this reason, we are saying that ArrayList is not thread-safe. Am i right?

Comment: There might be interference as for example blocking (a method call waiting for another call in a different thread to be finished). Caveats like this should be documented in the class' JavaDoc.

But there won't be any corrupted data or ConcurrentModificationExceptions or anything like this.